# intellij ide shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering, if anyone know about this kind of shortcut:
lets say I'm searching for something and get a results window with many results, is there a shortcut that can navigate me inside the list without mouse help?

Comment: So unhelpful.  This is IntelliJ.  Do you use ReSharper with VS?  If not, how does this apply?

Comment: just trying to help with explaining the question...

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2

Whenever I do a "Find in Path" using Ctrl+Shift+F and the search completes, the focus is already in the search results and the arrow keys can be used to navigate.

If the focus isn't in the search window, there can be an Alt+# combo that will take you to the window.  In my setup, it is Alt+3 (the label on my "Find" tab is "3: Find", so it's easy to see that Alt-3 is the right combo.)

I suspect that I may not understand what you're looking for, but maybe it is helpful.